# How can I figure out who or what kills my windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I've got a windows service that monitors user activity and run a process when nobody is logged in. It works fine on 22 PC and I've got an issue on 2 PCs.
On all PCs Service is configured to auto restart on error infinite times
When user logged off, my service dies in a minute on this 2 PCs, I've got a message in Event viewer that service stopped unexpectedly.
Service restarts in a minute and dies after one more minute, and so on.

NB: when service dies because of internal error I see Exception in logs

I want to figure out, who or what kills my service, how can I do it on windows 10? May be there is a way to intercept kill signal?

UPD: I did found service that where killing my one (logic worked). But the question is still on the top: how to find the source of kill message?

Comment: "I see Exception in logs" - but you didn't tell us any details about the exception?

Comment: Can you please post the exception logs. Just repair the OS of 2 PCs you are facing issues with.

Comment: it does not matter, cause when I see an exception it's ok, it is my scope to handle it, but the question is, how to find a killer, when there is no Exception at all!